# dhclient times out (wired only)

Tags: fedora, dhcp

(This is also posted on fedoraforum.org, but it may be interesting to people who use other distros.)

Hey all,

I've been struggling with trying to connect my Dell Inspiron 17 7731 running Fedora 23 to my office wired network for a few weeks now (wireless works fine).

Some relevant information:

```
# lspci
--snip--
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
--snip--

# uname -r
4.2.8-300.fc23.x86_64

# ifconfig
enp3s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:2a:72:a2:66:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 343  bytes 64568 (63.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 141 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16551  bytes 2027803 (1.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16551  bytes 2027803 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.124.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.124.255
        ether 52:54:00:3d:9c:4c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.26.63.219  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.26.63.255
        inet6 fe80::8286:f2ff:fe7e:9f6e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:86:f2:7e:9f:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 52385  bytes 48933298 (46.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32812  bytes 11212005 (10.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's some log output:

```
Jan 09 13:10:24 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 09 13:10:24 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  Activation (enp3s0f1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 09 13:10:24 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  dhclient started with pid 10973
Jan 09 13:10:24 mekagojira dhclient[10973]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x72a3fc32)
Jan 09 13:10:25 mekagojira avahi-daemon[878]: Registering new address record for fe80::ba2a:72ff:fea2:66db on enp3s0f1.*.
Jan 09 13:10:30 mekagojira dhclient[10973]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x72a3fc32)
Jan 09 13:10:33 mekagojira audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 09 13:10:43 mekagojira dhclient[10973]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x72a3fc32)
Jan 09 13:10:44 mekagojira dhclient[7221]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x32509905)
Jan 09 13:10:48 mekagojira dhclient[7221]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x32509905)
Jan 09 13:10:55 mekagojira dhclient[7221]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x32509905)
Jan 09 13:10:58 mekagojira dhclient[10973]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x72a3fc32)
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <warn>  (enp3s0f1): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10973
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <warn>  (enp3s0f1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 2'
Jan 09 13:11:08 mekagojira NetworkManager[1064]: <info>  (enp3s0f1): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
```

And here's the output of running dhclient on its own:

```
# dhclient -v enp3s0f1 
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:a2:66:db
Sending on   LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:a2:66:db
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x4b27e968)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4b27e968)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x4b27e968)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x4b27e968)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x4b27e968)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0x4b27e968)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Here's what I know (or guess at least):

- The DHCP server is up and not rejecting Linux clients, and the cable
  is fine. I plugged it into another box running Ubuntu 15.10 and
  connected right away.
- The NIC is fine on this machine. While a F23 live image behaves like
  the installation (i.e., fails to connect), an Ubuntu live image connects just fine.
- It's not this version (or just this version) of the kernel. The older ones on the GRUB menu also failed to connect.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that now wired fails to connect even with the same Ubuntu live image, and bringing it home and plugging it into an Apple AirPort (with no history of arbitrarily rejecting DHCP lessees petitioning via wired Ethernet) gives the same results, using several cables. I'm chalking this up to a hardware problem and closing it.